# How is group theory used to deduce which of these integrals are equal to 0?

Tags: electronic-structure, mathematical-modeling, symmetry, integrals, space-groups

The number of all two-electron integrals:
$$
\tag{1}
\langle \phi_1 \phi_2|\phi_3\phi_4 \rangle = \int d^3\mathbf r' \int d^3\mathbf r'' \, \phi_1(\mathbf r'') \, \phi_2(\mathbf r') \frac{1}{|\mathbf r' - \mathbf r''|} \, \phi_3(\mathbf r') \, \phi_4(\mathbf r''),
$$

for $N$ number of basis functions (I am using real-valued ones) is $N^4$.

Not all of them are unique, but the number of unique integrals is $N(N+1)(N^2 + N + 2)/8$.

Yet this number is still huge for a reasonably accurate basis set. I have a feeling that this number can be significantly reduced if one makes use of the **point-group symmetry** of the molecule to determine the vanishing integrals. If yes, **how is this done given the knowledge of the point group?**

Comment: +1. A question that I absolutely love! I have my hands tied with something for the next few hours, but I'm sure someone will love to answer this!

Comment: Related discussion (though without a full answer): https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/105125/41556

Comment: Programs like MOLPRO & CFOUR will usually detect the point group symmetry automatically, and will avoid calculating all unnecessary integrals. Other programs might calculate all the integrals and then these unnecessary integrals will be lost anyway when all integrals smaller than $10^{-N}$ are discarded (N can usually be specified in the input file, and is often 12 or 13 by default). What is your goal here, do you want to write your own electronic structure code and you want to make use of spatial symmetry to reduce the # of integrals, or do you just want a practical way (such as a software).

Comment: I am writing my own minimal electronic structure code. And yes I am planning to make use of the symmetry of the geometry to reduce the no. of 2-electron integrals. The $10^{-N}$ method seems quite straightforward and simple to implement but if the original number of integrals is big, I imagine it will result in some overhead time in the entire execution time.

Comment: you dont have to outline the method elaborately, I am grateful with just references.

Comment: @nougako Thanks for the clarification. I felt generous and really like this question so I put a bounty.

Comment: The second question "how to identify the point group symmetry computationally?" would be appropriate for a second question. I worry that having 2 questions in one can be discouraging for users that know the answer to one question but not the other, or don't have time to answer both. "Figuring out which integrals are zero based on the point group", is a different from "figuring out the point group".

Comment: @NikeDattani I followed your suggestion and made split the second question to a new one here https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/1789/are-there-computational-methods-for-the-determination-of-the-point-group-symmetr.

Comment: @nougako for more on the screening methods, see the section on the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality [here](http://folk.uio.no/helgaker/talks/SostrupIntegrals_10.pdf) you can compute a few specific integrals that will tell you whether many others are below some threshold and thus not needed.

Comment: @Tyberius I didn't know that the screening method which was probably what Nike refers to earlier was a bit more elaborate than just plainly scanning over all the unique integrals which was what I thought it is. My memory was a bit hazy on Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, I probably forgot that it also applies on inner products with an operator in between. Using screening method, I only need to precalculate and scan through all the diagonal elements, then store them since their numbers is at most just $N^2$.

Comment: The off-diagonal ones can then be compared against the product of the paired diagonal elements to decide its significance.

Comment: Right, you only need to compute the off-diagonal ones if the corresponding product of diagonal element square roots is above your specified threshold.

Comment: nougako: Would you mind delaying the "accepting" of an answer until the bounty period is over?  I don't want people to feel discouraged from going for the 300 points, by thinking that there's nothing left to add.

Comment: Thanks for delaying the "accept" action for a bit :) I've sent the question to people who might be interested in providing an answer. A question I get a lot is whether this is a molecule or a molecular crystal (the answer would vary based on this). Since you talk about point groups rather than space groups, and since you say "symmetry of the molecule" not "symmetry of the material" or "symmetry of the crystal", and since you say you're using Gaussians (not plane-waves), I'm guessing you're talking about a molecule, not a molecular crystal? It would be nice if you could just confirm this please

Comment: @NikeDattani Exactly, I am more interested in molecules.

Comment: It's on Twitter: https://twitter.com/StackMatter/status/1289309994589003780 You can re-tweet for more attention.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The question is too broad to be answered directly so I will provide a somewhat general scheme.

Basically in an integral like
$$
\int  d\mu A B C
$$
one would seek to expand each part in irreducible representations of a given group, say for instance
\begin{align}
B=\frac{1}{\vert \mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}^\prime\vert}
=\frac{1}{r} \sum_{\ell} \left(\frac{r'}{r}\right)^\ell \sqrt{\frac{4\pi}{2\ell+1}}Y^{\ell}_0(\theta,\varphi)
\end{align}
where here the group would be $SO(3)$ and the irreducible representations are labelled by $\ell$.  Doing the same for $C$ and $A$, *v.g.*
\begin{align}
C&=\sum_{\ell m} c_{\ell m}Y^\ell_{m}(\theta,\varphi)\, ,\\
A&=\sum_{\ell m} a_{\ell m}Y^\ell_{m}(\theta,\varphi)\, .
\end{align}
The integral then becomes
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{r}\sum_{\ell_1m_1;\ell_2m_2;\ell}
a_{\ell_1m_1}c_{\ell_2m_2}\left(\frac{r'}{r}\right)^\ell 
\sqrt{\frac{4\pi}{2\ell+1}}
\int Y^{\ell_1}_{m_1}(\theta,\varphi)Y^\ell_0(\theta,\varphi)
Y^{\ell_2}_{m_2}(\theta,\varphi) \tag{1}
\end{align}
and the last term is automatically $0$ unless we have
\begin{align}
\ell_1\otimes\ell\otimes\ell_2&=\mathbf{0}+\ldots...\,  , \tag{2a}\\
m_1+m_2&=0 \tag{2b}
\end{align}
where (2a) comes from angular momentum coupling to the representation $\mathbf{0}$ (i.e. total $L=0$) and (2b) is the condition on $SO(2)\sim U(1)$ that the resulting magnetic quantum number is $0$.

There is nothing *a priori* to restrict the sum over $\ell_1,\ell_2,\ell$ in (1) unless you have some prior knowledge of $A$, $B$ and $C$.

The same general principle holds for point groups.  In the case of
point groups you would expand each $A$, $B$, $C$ in terms of representation of the specific point group, and use the great orthogonality theorem of representations (also called [Schur orthogonality relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_orthogonality_relations#Coordinates_statement)).  Probably the integral would be broken in group elements multiplied by cosets, i.e .the integration would be written as $g\cdot h$ where $g$ is in the group, and some sums over $g$ would be $0$ if the combination of representations contained in the decomposition of $A$, $B$ and $C$ can be combined to the identity (or trivial) representation.  There would then remain integration over cosets.  This is *a bit* of what happens in the example above: writing a rotation as $R_z(\varphi) R_y(\theta)$ (there is no third angle here) the condition $m_1+m_2=0$ gets rid of the $R_z(\varphi)$ integration and the result is an integration over $R_y(\theta)$ only.

[Prof. Mildred Dresselhaus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mildred_Dresselhaus) of MIT still has [coursenotes available](http://web.mit.edu/course/6/6.734j/www/group-full02.pdf), and co-wrote an excellent textbook on the general topic.

Edit:

So it seems your “real solid harmonics“ are basically the same as my spherical harmonics, up to some linear combinations.

0. I do not understand your comment re: Hilbert space.  The Hilbert space here is the space of all 2-particle states (as you have written your states as products of two states).

So a more or less general procedure would be as follows.

1. Find the linear combinations of your basis sets that transform by irreducible representations of your points group.   For instance, if you “only” need axial symmetry, then combinations of the type $Y^\ell_m\pm Y^\ell_{-m}$ will produce cosine and sine pieces that are symmetric or antisymmetric w/r to reversal of the $\hat z$ axis.  There are systematic ways of finding these, using projection operator techniques (someone already pointed that out).
2. This decomposition is usually not that bad if the group has few representations but then some irreps may occur more than once and it can be a computational headache unless one is careful.  In other words, the projection technique might provide you with multiple solutions which you have to specialize and properly normalize.   The projection gives you (usually) one state in the irrep and you may have to work a little more to construct the remaining states, although with point groups the matrix representations are well known so it’s not that bad.
3. Basically the step above means you are no longer working with functions $\boldsymbol{\phi_3}\boldsymbol{\phi_4}$ in your original basis set but some combinations of states. You also need to expand the Coulomb term in this way.
4. The last step is to use orthogonality of group functions to eliminate some terms.  The non-zero terms that survive are those for which the tensor product $\Gamma^*_k\otimes \Gamma_r\otimes \Gamma_i$ contains the identity representation.  Here, $\Gamma^*_k$ is one piece in the sum of the expansion of $\phi_1\phi_2$, $\Gamma_r$ is one piece in the sum of the expansion of $1/\vert\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}\vert$, and $\Gamma_i$ is one piece in the expansion of $\phi_3\phi_4$.  This type of triple product may occur more than once for $(k,r,i)$ if the irreps $\Gamma_k$ *etc* occur more than once in the decomposition of the old basis set in the basis set.

You get to decide if finding these combinations ends up saving time over simply evaluating the original integrals.

Comment: This is probably a bit more general than what OP had in mind (molecular and crystallographic point groups are fairly restricted in the types of irreps that can occur, which makes most of the work just determining the multiplication table for the group and finding what combinations give the totally symmetric representation), but a great answer all the same.

Comment: @Tyberius right but unless you know something of $\vert\phi_i\rangle$ you're swimming in a very big ocean.  Tell me the point group and I can go forward.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero The question asks how to "use the point group" to move forward. So it is assumed that you know the point group and you now want to eliminate integrals. Tyberius [here's a chat chain](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55076783#55076783) with the answerer: which provides some context.

Comment: @NikeDattani right but then you decompose everything in terms of irreps for that point group and check to see if the trivial irrep appears.  This is bit like saying: given a general integral and knowledge that it can be done by trig substitution under what condition will this integral be $0$?   Unless you are given the actual integral even if you know that is can be done in a certain way is not terribly helpful.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Are you saying that we need to know the $\phi$ functions given in the question? Meaning, not just that they are Gaussian or Slater orbitals, but we need to know the specific values of the Gaussian or Slater exponents?

Comment: @NikeDattani the decomposition into irréductibles will depend on the functions so yes the answer will certainly be different for different types of functions.  There’s this great paper by Bethe, H.A., 1997. Splitting of terms in crystals. In Selected Works Of Hans A Bethe: (With Commentary) (pp. 1-72) which gives quite a bit of details also.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero thanks for the time. What I am interested in is the general prescription, i.e. the (potentially equation-less) step-by-step kind of instruction to determine the vanishing integrals. But its okay I get the idea from your answer. As for what are $\phi_i$'s, they are atom-centered contracted Gaussian type orbital, that is, the radial part is some linear combinations of radial Gaussian functions and the angular part is the so-called real solid harmonics.

Comment: In your example, you assume that $A$ and $C$ live in the same 1-electron Hilbert space. In the integral in the original question, do I need to simply tensor-product the four $\phi_i$'s? I feel like doing this will disregard the fact that, e.g. $\phi_3$ and $\phi_4$, belong to different Hilbert spaces.

Comment: @nougako thanks for the query... will update within 48hrs

Comment: By Hilbert space I mean the space of all 1-particle functions in which $\phi_i$'s belong. Since $\phi_3$ and $\phi_4$ are associated to different electrons, I am wondering if that should somehow affect the procedure described in your original answer.

Answer (score 9):

First, you have to transform all the basis functions into the irreducible representations (irreps) of the point group of the molecule. You can do this with standard projection formulas.

Once, you know the irreps of the basis functions, you have to look at the product table of the point group to find out whether the product of those four basis functions contains the totally symmetric irrep. If it does, then the integral has to be computed. Otherwise you know it is vanishing.

I think a good reference is Albert Cotton's "Chemical Applications of Group Theory"

Comment: So, it's very similar to the rule of addition of angular momenta I guess and it looks like the addition of angular momenta is a special case of the rule you described above for a system with infinite number of symmetries, i.e. the spherical symmetry like a single atom.

Comment: And is the reason the irreps resulting from the tensor product of the four functions must contain totally symmetric irrep is because $1/|\mathbf r - \mathbf r'|$ is symmetric with respect to inversion of both vectors? Then if my operator is such that $f(-\mathbf r, -\mathbf r') = -f(\mathbf r, \mathbf r')$, do I need the product of the four functions to contain totally antisymmetric irreps? The $f$ operator before can depend on the individual orientations of the two vectors.

Comment: The general rule is that the product of the irreps of all wavefunctions and operators has to contain the totally symmetric irrep. What you are saying sounds right. The electron repulsion is the only two-electron operator people usually care about and this is totally symmetric. But things get a bit more interesting when you are looking at dipole and quadrupole selectron rules for IR and Raman spectroscopy - then you also have to consider the irrep of the operator.

Answer (score 5):

To start with, while it's not as necessary, you can apply symmetry arguments to one-electron integrals. Consider $\langle\mu|O_1|\nu\rangle$, where $O_1$ is some one-electron operator. If the molecule has some point group symmetry, we can form basis functions/operators that are irreducible representations of the group. Once we have the functions expressed in terms of irreps (as described in a [question](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/1789/are-there-computational-methods-for-the-determination-of-the-point-group-symmetr?r=SearchResults) here), we can easily determine which integrals must vanish just from the group multiplication table: $$\Gamma_{\text{TSR}}\notin\Gamma_\mu \otimes\Gamma_{O_1} \otimes\Gamma_\nu\to\langle\mu|O_1|\nu\rangle=0$$ Here, $\Gamma_x$ is the irrep of $x$ and TSR is the totally symmetric representation. So if the symmetric representation is not in the product of the irreps, the integral must vanish.

To give a concrete example, consider a water molecule, which has $C_{2v}$ symmetry ([character table](http://symmetry.jacobs-university.de/cgi-bin/group.cgi?group=402&option=4)) We can look at the very simple example of overlap integrals ($O_1=1$). In this case, the integrals will only be nonzero when the irrep of $\mu$ and $\nu$ are the same, as this ensures the TSR is in their product. In the best case in terms of reducing the cost, you will have an equal number of basis functions of each irrep. For water, this would reduce the number of overlap integrals needed from $(N^2+N)/2$ to $(\frac{N^2}{4}+N)/2$ where the $4$ comes from the number of irreps.

Two electron integrals are in principle the same, but involve 4 functions rather than 2. Also, we are almost always interested in the Coulomb operator, which is totally symmetric, so we only need to consider the irreps of the 4 functions. We can reduce this to looking at the symmetry of pairs of functions/charge distributions to make the evaluation basically the same as the case of the overlap integrals, though obviously with many more integrals. Combined with integral screening (e.g Cauchy-Schwarz) you can see a fairly substantial reduction in size. While Hartree-Fock is formally $O(N^4)$ due to forming the 2e integrals, in practice with codes that's use integral screening and symmetry this can be reduced to less than $O(N^3)$.

Others have mentioned the limits of applying symmetry and that many molecules in for example biology have no symmetry. However, there are areas like inorganic chemistry, where many molecules of interest are symmetric or nearly so. This can used to accelerate, as an example, geometry optimizations by using the idealized, symmetric geometry, which can be obtained at reduced cost, as a guess to obtain the true, nearly symmetric structure.

Answer (score 4):

Boy, you're not starting off easy. Proper implementation of symmetry is quite a job, especially since most systems of interest nowadays have no symmetry.

For a reference, you can look at e.g. Dovesi's work on the use of symmetry in CRYSTAL, which is a periodic Hartree-Fock code using Gaussian orbitals. Symmetry is much more important in the periodic case, since the periodic packing introduces many more symmetries than in molecules. However, at the $\Gamma$ point (${\bf k}={\bf 0}$) you're essentially reduced to molecular symmetry. (CRYSTAL can use symmetry with periodic boundaries in 0, 1, 2, or 3 dimensions for molecules, rods, planes, and crystalline systems.)

[Int. J. Quantum Chem 29, 1755 (1986)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/qua.560290608)

Comment: Yeah I know, I expected that the answer is nothing close to being straightforward. I also know that symmetry becomes less significant if I am also interested in non-equilibrium geometries but I think its still useful to know the concept.